# Set value in field in redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have redux form having dropdown and text fields. On dropdown change i have to update the other fields. The other fields are using custom component example

So the structure is like.
1. component having form
2. Field component.

Now i googled and found few things to update the field but not able to do it.
What i tried
1. Adding state in the field like below in value. Does not work.

```
<Field name="accountno" value="this.state.accountno" component={InputText} placeholder="Number" />
```

2. Tried disptach but not able to use it. Getting error for no dispatch i prop type

   this.props.dispatch(change('form', 'accountno', 'test value'));
3. Tried this.props.fields but same not fields in props type.

It should work using 2 or 3 but not able to find where to add those. Please let me know how can i use these or any other way.

Comment: You should validate `onChange` as a property of `input` with `PropTypes.shape`.

Comment: @juliobetta where should i add that?

Comment: WOW! This is a complete different question now =). well, IMHO, I don't think you should validate all `redux-form` methods and props (`onChange`, `disabled`, etc...) in your custom input component, unless they are required. But answering your question, take a look at this article http://andrewhfarmer.com/validate-nested-proptypes. It shows how to use the proptype `shape`.

Answer (score 34):

When using `redux-form`, you don't need to set the value directly into the field. You can use the method `initialize` to populate your form. Or `initialValues` as a property of the object passed to `redux` to map state to props. The other way is to set the values individually using the function `change` from `redux-form`. In order to make it to work, you need to wrap your component with `connect` from `react-redux`. It embeds the `dispatch` method in your props.

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field, change } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Form extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initialize({ accountno: 'some value here' });
    // set the value individually
    this.props.dispatch(change('myFormName', 'anotherField', 'value'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={...}>
        ...
        <Field name="accountno" component={InputText} placeholder="Number" />
        <Field name="anotherField" component={InputText} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

Form = reduxForm({ 
  form: 'myFormName' 
})(Form);

export default connect(state => ({ 
  // alternatively, you can set initial values here...
  initialValues: {
    accountno: 'some value here'
  } 
}))(Form);
```

Comment: i have tried all these options, none are working. i have it set like `SecurityExemptionsNew = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    SecurityExemptionsNew
);

//Decorate the form component
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'SecurityExemptionsNewForm', // a unique name for this form
    initialValues: { service_domain: 'Corporate (Internal/External)' }
})(SecurityExemptionsNew);
`

Comment: ```change()``` worked for me better than initalValues becasue ```initialize``` rerenderd my entire page and made it useless where change only rerenderd that input. thanks julio

Comment: I've been looking for `change` option for many pages, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 10):

Just came up against this issue as well.  The solution is to use `initialValues` as in juliobetta's answer, however the key is to set the value to a variable, such as `state.blah`.

You then need to [set `enableReinitialize` to `true`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/examples/initializeFromState/src/InitializeFromState.md) so that the fields get updated when the state changes:

```
export default connect(state => ({ 
  initialValues: {
    accountno: state.accountno,
  },
  enableReinitialize: true,
}))(Form);
```

Now, every time you change `state.accountno`, the form field will be updated.

Comment: This has a drawback in that it will reset other form fields that the user may have modified back to their initial values; in other words you can't use it for both initial values and for setting some field values dynamically, and have to track the entire state inside `initialValues`. It just starts to feel like working against redux. Maybe there is a workaround.